# Data didn't pass in Ajax login

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I am beginner in `PHP` and `Ajax`. I am developing login form with `session` using both languages with `MySql` looking a video tutorial. Finally I got the the error like whether the `email` or `password` incorrect it redirect to the welcome page.

Code is below:

```
<style>
  #box{
    width:100%;
    max-width:500px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0 20px;
    box-sizing:boader-box;
    height:270px;
  }
</style>

<div id=box>
  <form method="POST" class="form-signin">
    <div class="account-logo">
      <img src="assets/img/logo-dark.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label> Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" autofocus="" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password"class="formcontrol">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-right">
      <a href="forgot-password.html">Forgot your password?</a>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
      <input type="button"  class="btn btn-primary account-btn" name="login" value="DO LOGIN" id="login_button">
    </div>
    <div id="error">       </div>
    <div class="text-center register-link">
      Don’t have an account? <a href="register.html">Register Now</a>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The Ajax query will be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#login_button').click(function(){
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();

    if($.trim(email).length>0 && $.trim(password).length>0 ){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",  // Type of request to be send, called as method
        url: "auth/logged.php", // Url to which the request is send
        data: {"email":email,"password":password},
        cache:false,
        beforeSend:function()
        {
          $('#login_button').val("connecting.....");
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
          if(data){
            $('body').load("index.php").hide().fadeIn(1500);
          }else{
            var option ={
              distace :'40',
              direction:'left',
              times:3
            }
            $('#box').effect('shake',option,800);
            $('#login_button').val('Login');
            $('#error').html("<span class='text-danger'> Invalid username or password </span>");
          }
        }
      });
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

The logged.php will be

```
<?php
  include "dbconnection.php";
  session_start();

  if (isset($_POST['email'])  && isset($_POST['password']) ) {
    $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email'] );
    $password=md5(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']) );
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '". $email."'  AND '". $password."'  ";
    $result= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $num_row= mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($num_row>0)
    {
      $data=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      $_SESSION['username']=$data['username'];
     echo $data['username'];
    }
  }
?>
```

Whenever I entered any data whether it is right or wrong it redirect to the welcome page. Please help me.

- List item

Comment: When you say you are redirected to the welcome page, what does that mean?  Your ajax request doesn't look like it's doing any sort of redirect logic, and the login button in your form is of type button, not submit, so the form shouldn't be submitting if you click that button.

Comment: Don't use MD5 for passwords, it's useless. Use`password_hash()`

Comment: your SQL is incorrect doesn't contain the second field name. If you are learning the concept then it ok to use plain SQL query otherwise you should always use prepared statement (PDO) in production and always store the encrypted  passwords

Comment: @Taplar if we use type `submit` the page will `refresh`. that is why i put type `button`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this on your logged.php:

```
<?php
    include "dbconnection.php";
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['email'])  && isset($_POST['password']) ) {
        // I don't see your password column name, so I guess it is password
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE email=? AND password=?")) {
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = md5($_POST['password']);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $password);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username);
            
            echo mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: it shows like this  in `Ajax query`:                                                                                                          
`success: function(data)  -- data = "<br />↵<b>Notice</b>:  Only variables should be passed by reference in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Hospital\adminpanel\auth\logged.php</b> on line`                     Line is  `mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $_POST['email'], md5($_POST['password']));`

Comment: what does echo mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt); and (especially ) echo false; do?

Comment: @YourCommonSense it for ajax success callback sir

Comment: echo false; will do nothing.